# Delete elements from string + transform it into array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have this string : 
`data = "[\"super\", \"cool!\", \"bien écrit\", \"first!\", \"why is everyone speaking French here?\"]"`

I would like to transform it to be like :
`data = ["super", "cool!", "bien écrit", "first!", "why is everyone speaking French here?"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse it like a JSON. Try

```
require 'json'
data = JSON.parse data
```

Comment: This is actually not Json. It's saved like that 
 Comment.create!(
        content:["super", "cool!", "bien écrit", "first!", "why is everyone speaking French here?"]
      );
So when I want to display it it return me a string

Comment: So? It's a valid JSON.

Comment: @Orsay You show us string in data variable and this string is valid JSON like Ursus say.

Comment: You may want to serialize the content attribute : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize

Answer (score 1):

The data looks like JSON. parse it using `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: This is actually not Json. It's saved like that 
 Comment.create!(
        content:["super", "cool!", "bien écrit", "first!", "why is everyone speaking French here?"]
      );
So when I want to display it it return me a string